# Python - Nested List to Tab Delimited File?

Tags: python, list, nested, csv

I have a nested list comprising ~30,000 sub-lists, each with three entries, e.g.,

```
nested_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']].
```

I wish to create a function in order to output this data construct into a tab delimited format, e.g.,

```
x    y    z
a    b    c
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,
Seafoid.

Comment: What do you have so far?  Any code attempt that partially works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
with open('fname', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines('\t'.join(i) + '\n' for i in nested_list)
```

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> nested_list = [['x', 'y', 'z'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]
>>> for line in nested_list:
...   print '\t'.join(line)
... 
x   y   z
a   b   c
>>>
```

Comment: Just curious would it help to store sublists as 3-tuples instead of lists? performance wise?

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer: Feel free to use `timeit` to see what the actual impact actually is. http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html

Comment: @TheMachineCharmer: note that the real code probably doesn't have the lists hard-coded this way, but reads them from a file or gets them from another source

Answer (score 5):

In my view, it's a simple one-liner:

```
print '\n'.join(['\t'.join(l) for l in nested_list])
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print '\n'.join(map('\t'.join,nested_list))
x       y       z
a       b       c
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
out = file("yourfile", "w")
for line in nested_list:
    print >> out, "\t".join(line)
```